# Populate value with Beautifulsoup when tag is empty

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm trying to parse out the contents of all the td tags of a certain class in a webpage, but I want to have placeholder content of some kind even if the tag itself doesn't have any. For example, the html contains td tags like this:

```
<td class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds " cfg="">+134</td>
<td class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds " cfg=""></td>
<td class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds " cfg="">-140</td>
```

I'm trying to get a list like ['+134', '-', '-140'] as output, so the number of entries in the list is equal to the number of matching tags with '-' as a placeholder denoting the tag was empty. The below, however, just returns ['+134','-140'].

```
soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'odds bdevtt moneylineodds '})
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is use `or` operator:

```
out = [td.get_text(strip=True) or '-' for td in soup.select('td.odds.bdevtt.moneylineodds')]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['+134', '-', '-140']
```

---

Some quick benchmark:

```
txt = '''<td class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds " cfg="">+134</td>
<td class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds " cfg=""></td>
<td class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds " cfg="">-140</td>'''
​
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from timeit import timeit
​
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
​
def using_or():
    return [td.get_text(strip=True) or '-' for td in soup.select('td.odds.bdevtt.moneylineodds')]
​
def using_if_else_1():
    return [td.text if td.text else '-' for td in soup.select('td.odds.bdevtt.moneylineodds')]
​
def using_if_else_2():
    return [t if (t := td.get_text(strip=True)) else '-' for td in soup.select('td.odds.bdevtt.moneylineodds')]
​
​
t1 = timeit(lambda: using_or(), number=10_000)
t2 = timeit(lambda: using_if_else_1(), number=10_000)
t3 = timeit(lambda: using_if_else_2(), number=10_000)
​
print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
​
```

This prints:

```
0.7735823660041206
0.8084569670027122
0.776867889042478
```

As seems, the solutions are +/- the same performance wise.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know how `or` compares with `if else` efficiency wise?

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Wonder what is going on with 2 and 3. Perhaps even out over larger test size.

Comment: @QHarr I let them run 1_000_000 times each, and the results are `78.19792580400826, 81.93139944702853, 79.0471791360178`, so yeah `or` method has _slight_ lead. The method `2` is losing because `td.text` is accessed 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<td class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds " cfg="">+134</td>
<td class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds " cfg=""></td>
<td class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds " cfg="">-140</td>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
all = [i.text if i.text != "" else "-" for i in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'odds bdevtt moneylineodds '})]
print(all)

# output: ['+134', '-', '-140']
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing space from the value of `class` attribute and you will get the expected result.

**Code:**

```py
for elm in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'odds bdevtt moneylineodds'}):
  print(elm.text)
```

**Output:**

```
+134

-140
```

Reason for this is when you execute the code

```py
html = """
<td class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds " cfg="">+134</td>
<td class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds " cfg=""></td>
<td class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds " cfg="">-140</td>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")   # <-- It will trim the trailing spaces from class value
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<td cfg="" class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds">+134</td>
<td cfg="" class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds"></td>
<td cfg="" class="odds bdevtt moneylineodds">-140</td>
```